# How to grab data from table with divs and inputs inside cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am still new to js and jQuery.  How would I iterate through the table and grab data from each cell (the date, and input "from" and "to")?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" id="entryTable">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>First Shift</th>
        <th>Second Shift</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>2/1/2016</td>
            <td>
                <div id="time" class="form-group">
                    From: <input type="text" id="start01"> 
                    To: <input type="text" id="end01">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="time" class="form-group">
                    From: <input type="text" id="start02" > 
                    To: <input type="text" id="end02">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496108/how-to-iterate-through-table-and-sum-values-jquery/35496165#35496165

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate a table rows with JQuery and access some cell values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891357/how-to-iterate-a-table-rows-with-jquery-and-access-some-cell-values)

Comment: First change your id= to class=. You cannot have multiple id attributes with the same value. class= is for the type of value you could say. id= should uniquely identify the element.

Comment: @Michael I dont see any repeated id's in his code above, Am i missing something?

Comment: @Reddy `<div id="time" ... >` but that is less important.

Comment: @Michael ah I see it now, i missed it because as you said its less important here.

Comment: @Reddy, what about updating your answer with a better solution for the HTML in stead? Better class semantics. So that you could do  `$('.first-shift .from').eq(0);` instead?

Comment: thanks guys.  i forgot i was hardcoding the div ids. will fix that.  in terms of reddy's code I am digesting it and really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is a Jsfiddle I built for you [JsFiddle To Get table values](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/c1kaftre/1/)

And the code I used is

```
  var date = $('#entryTable').find('tbody td:eq(0)').text();

  var From01 = $('#entryTable').find('tbody td:eq(1) input:eq(0)').val();
  var To01 = $('#entryTable').find('tbody td:eq(1) input:eq(1)').val();

  var From02 = $('#entryTable').find('tbody td:eq(2) input:eq(0)').val();
  var To02 = $('#entryTable').find('tbody td:eq(2) input:eq(1)').val();
```

In the Fiddle I have put a button to fetch the value on click of the button, I am displaying the values in alert, you can change the code according to your requirement
 - List item

**EDIT:** To loop through all the td's you can do this

```
$.each($('#entryTable').find('tbody td), function(){
         var currentTdOfLoop = $(this);
        //do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: since the table is dynamic, can I insert an int var in place of the number so I can iterate through all the td's?  ie. `var count = 0`  `'tbody td:eq('count')'` , `tbody td:eq('(count+1) ')`,  `tbody td:eq('(count+2) ')`, etc?

Comment: Yes you can do that, But you use `eq()` selector when you want to select specific element by index. if you just want to loop through all the td's you can use `$.each`. I have updated my answer for you to show how to loop all td's

Answer (score 0):

in javascript you can use the method `document.getElementById("tagId")` for example in your case `document.getElementById("time")` or you can use `document.getElementByClassName("tagClassName") or document.getElementByTagName("TagName")` and each of them returns an array of dom elements in JQuery library it's so similar to css selectors for example

```
$("#elementId") to select an element by its id 
$(".className") to select an elements by their class name 
$("tagname") like $("p") to select all the p tags in the dom 
$("div p") to select the p tags which in a div tag 
and for example in your code you can grape a th element in your table using a selector like that $("#entryTable > thead th:nth-child(2)")
```

and I think that

Comment: thanks Rami for the help. I will definitely look through W3Schools :D